# Return data from table if 2 other columns in 2 tables match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup-tables

I have 2 sheets, both sheet have Plan ID and Ticker in columns A and B. One sheet includes a count that we need to lookup into the first sheet, can't just format that sheet because it also has a lot of extra rows of data in it for other accounts. Trying to return ppt counts from sheet 1 to the second sheet when both plan ID and ticker columns match.

Tried various if, match, vlookup xlookup attempts, nothing is returning. I know combining A/B columns to a unique vlookup would help simplify formula but that just makes another thing we have to clean up after.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data tables start in ColA with headers (PlanID, Ticker, PPT) and the data starts in row 2. `Sheet2` should be where the data comes from. The real thing to ensure is that the table and columns you references are the same height, meaning you highlight the whole table top to bottom for each, if one array has more cells than the other it won't evaluate properly.

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$13, MATCH(1, (Sheet1!A4=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$13)*(Sheet1!B4=Sheet2!$B$1:$B$13) ,0),3)`

Breakdown:

`Index( [source table], match( 1, ( [PlanID] = [Column of planIDS you're pulling from]) *( [Ticker] = [Col of Tickers],0), [# of column PPT is in that table])`